# Joining 2 json string using c# or jobject or newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Hi given I have 2 json files and I would like to join them

```
{
    "PropertyOne": "PropOne",
    "PropertyTwo": "PropTwo",
    "PropertyThree": "PropThree"
}
```

and

```
{
    "MyObject": {
        "PropertyOne": "PropOne",
        "PropertyTwo": "PropTwo",
        "PropertyThree": "PropThree"
    }
}
```

How can I join them get the below outcome and be a valid json?

```
{
"PropertyOne": "PropOne",
"PropertyTwo": "PropTwo",
"PropertyThree": "PropThree",
"MyObject": {
    "PropertyOne": "PropOne",
    "PropertyTwo": "PropTwo",
  "PropertyThree": "PropThree"
}
```

}

Comment: @DanWilson sorry looks a duplicate but isnt that does not work in .net core/standard does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using Newtonsoft. It is available via Nuget for easy install.

```
string json1 = @"{'PropertyOne': 'PropOne','PropertyTwo': 'PropTwo','PropertyThree': 'PropThree'}";
string json2 = @"{'MyObject': {'PropertyOne': 'PropOne','PropertyTwo': 'PropTwo','PropertyThree': 'PropThree'}}";

JObject j1 = JObject.Parse(json1);
JObject j2 = JObject.Parse(json2);

j1.Merge(j2, new JsonMergeSettings {
    MergeArrayHandling = MergeArrayHandling.Union
});
```

Here you would create your two JSON string objects, parse both of them using JObject. Then using the merge method you can let Newtonsoft take care of it behind the scenes. The resulting `j1` object has your desired output.

Comment: yes.I did have newtonsoft.I tried few things but could not make it work .many thanks

Answer (score 0):

try below thing

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string jsonText = @"
        {
            ""propertyOne"": ""PropOne"",
            ""propertyTwo"": ""PropTwo"",
            ""propertyThree"": ""PropThree""
        }";

    string jsonText2 = @"
        {
            ""propertyOne"": ""PropOne"",
            ""propertyTwo"": ""PropTwo"",
            ""propertyThree"": ""PropThree""
        }";

    var jsonObj = JObject.Parse(jsonText);
    var jsonObj2 = JObject.Parse(jsonText2);

    if (jsonObj != null && jsonObj2 != null)
    {
        if (jsonObj["MyObject"] == null)
        {
            jsonObj.Add("MyObject", new JObject());
        }

        var myObject = jsonObj["MyObject"] as JObject;

        if (myObject != null)
        {
            myObject.Merge(jsonObj2);
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(jsonObj.ToString());
}
```

it's working for me

Comment: that works too ,i gave the answer to to ivcubr as he answered earlier sorry